# change boolean value

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am working on a Hotel Reservation Project in ASP.NET.
I want to make a filter so that I can search the room available by date (for example between 1 June and 5 June) and after that reserve that room .How can I do to change status of that room to "not available" for that period,so that somebody who want to reserve that room between 15 may and 30 may can do it.Status of the room is boolean value in my database.

[image]

Comment: So far i display all room with status available .But the status is set when i introduce the room in database.But I dont know how to change the staus and if it is posible to set status of a room as true for a period and then false for another period

Comment: You can handle this for UI purpose without using status field in DB by only check in date and check out date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

before displaying data on UI, you have to manipulate your room table everytime

```
var objrum = rum.toList().asQueryable(); // fetches all the rooms
var objreservation = reservation.toList().asQueryable(); // fetches all reservation

foreach(var res in objreservation)
{
    foreach(var rum in objrum)
    {
        if(res.roomid == rum.rumid)
        {
            if(res.checkindate >= currentcheckindate && res.checkoutdate <= currentcheckoutdate)
            {
                rum.status = false // set to unavailable
            }
            else
                rum.status = true // set to available
        }
    }
}
```

than fetch the data from room table for displaying on your UI

Comment: do changes in query as per your usage in code might be linq to object, or linq to entity ...

Comment: Your example could be rolled up into a smaller LINQ/Lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

The `'Status'` value changes and is based upon multiple things so you shouldnt really store it against your room table.

What you need to do in this case is write a query that looks at a date range and then returns the status based on your reservations table. So a user selects a date range and the query gets executed and returns a list of all the days with the status of available or booked.

Imagine if you did this

```
SELECT * FROM Reservation res LEFT JOIN Room ON res.Room_ID = Room.RoomId
```

Your room table has a status of Available so it will always return available for every single row. If you had this status as unavailable it would return unavailable for every row, even when the room was actually available.